# CakePHP 2.x multiple select box

Tags: cakephp, select, html-helper

I create by `$this->Form->input('field')` automatic populate multiple select box.

But how to use code above to select options in edit action which saved values?

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure your form is created with the correct model

   eg `$this->Form->create('Article');
2. pass a variable as the singular of your model from the Controller via `$this->set()`.  For example, if your model is "Article", then pass a variable with the data:

   `$this->set('article', $article);`
3. it will populate automatically
4. Next time you ask a question on StackOverflow, provide information on what you've tried, what worked, what didn't, what you've search for but couldn't find...etc, so it doesn't feel as though we're just writing code for you.

**Update (per additional info in comments):**

For HABTM, create your field with the model:

```
$this->Form->input('PartnerState');
```

Then pass a variable camelCase plural:

```
$this->set('partnerStates', $partnerStates);
```

Comment: Problem isn't it populate but selected options from db (edit action).

Comment: I create form for model Partner but the list for select is from PartnerState (HABTM).

Comment: Ok, this works, but when I use Edit Action, the populated field isn't selected (after saved)

Comment: Because you're not passing all the data.  You need to make sure your main Model's data Contains the HABTM data (look up CakePHP's Containable Behavior).

Comment: Okey, let's doing without db. I create field by $this->Form->select('Some field', array('AAAAA', 'BBBBB', 'CCCCC'), array('multiple' => true)); I select 'BBBBB' and send form, my other fields are invalidate but field 'Some field' haven't selected BBBBB value, why?

Comment: This is not the place to go step-by-step through your code to debug it for you.  Try StackOverlflow's 'chat': http://chat.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Okey, the problem was in 2.3.0, it's fixed in 2.3.1